# How to batch get items using servicestack.aws PocoDynamo?

Tags: servicestack, pocodynamo

With Amazon native .net lib, batchget is like this

```
var batch = context.CreateBatch<MyClass>();
batch.AddKey("hashkey1");
batch.AddKey("hashkey2");
batch.AddKey("hashkey3");
batch.Execute();
var result = batch.results;
```

Now I'm testing to use servicestack.aws, however I couldn't find how to do it. I've tried the following, both failed.

```
//1st try
var q1 = db.FromQueryIndex<MyClass>(x => x.room_id == "hashkey1" || x.room_id == "hashkey2"||x.room_id == "hashkey3");
var result = db.Query(q1);

//2nd try
var result = db.GetItems<MyClass>(new string[]{"hashkey1","hashkey2","hashkey3"});
```

In both cases, it threw an exception that says 
    Additional information: Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: OR

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GetItems should work as seen with this [Live Example on Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=2c2f154667b1ce1f6c32c37051f5e697&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

db.RegisterTable<MyClass>();

db.DeleteTable<MyClass>();  // Delete existing MyClass Table (if any)
db.InitSchema();         // Creates MyClass DynamoDB Table

var items = 5.Times(i => new MyClass { Id = $"hashkey{i}", Content = $"Content {i}" });
db.PutItems(items);

var dbItems = db.GetItems<MyClass>(new[]{ "hashkey1","hashkey2","hashkey3" });
"Saved Items: {0}".Print(dbItems.Dump());
```

If your Item has both a Hash and a Range Key you'll need to use the `GetItems<T>(IEnumerable<DynamoId> ids)` API, e.g:

```
var dbItems = db.GetItems<MyClass>(new[]{
    new DynamoId("hashkey1","rangekey1"),
    new DynamoId("hashkey2","rangekey3"),
    new DynamoId("hashkey3","rangekey4"),
});
```

#### Query all Items with same HashKey

If you want to fetch all items with the same HashKey you need to [create a DynamoDB Query](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo#queryexpressions-are-queryrequests) as seen with this [Live Gistlyn Example](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=37c08eed541dd11f20e72bf1e3657c01):

```
var items = 5.Times(i => new MyClass { 
    Id = $"hashkey{i%2}", RangeKey = $"rangekey{i}", Content = $"Content {i}" });
db.PutItems(items);

var rows = db.FromQuery<MyClass>(x => x.Id == "hashkey1").Exec().ToArray();
rows.PrintDump();
```

Comment: Thanks. I do have both hashkey and rangekey, I guess that's why it's not working for me. But what I want is I really don't care about the rangekey in this scenario, I just want to get all the record using hashkey (rangekey can equal to anything)

Comment: @shawhu in that case you need to create a query with just the HashKey, see my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks again. however, sorry for haven't stated clearly previously, I have a table that has both hashkey and rangekey, and I want to query using hashkey only but not one hashkey, I want to create a batch that query with multiple hashkeys on a table that has both hashkey and rangekey.

Comment: @shawhu Then you need to perform multiple queries, one per hash key. You can't batch queries to different hash keys by design, i.e. they have to query multiple logical partitions which is why DynamoDB doesn't let you query across different hash keys. You can use a [Scan to query across multiple partitions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo#getting-items-with-pocodynamo) but that does a full table scan and is therefore inefficient and not something you should do in production code without going through a caching layer to minimize full table scans.

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense. That's why the native Ddb c# lib also doesn't provide such function. I would probably use c# do multiple queries and merge them together manually.